# In Scala how do I apply a method to a variable before sorting a List on that variable?

Tags: scala

For example suppose I have

```
val sortedSignal = signal.sortBy(_.variable)
```

And I wish to apply Math.abs to variable before sorting.  What is the correct syntax for doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
signal.sortBy(x=>Math.abs(x.variable))
```

Comment: A little shorter: `signal.sortBy(_.variable.abs)`